# refactor jQuery to fade and stop it from crashing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

This js works but after a while it crashes any browser thats open. Do I have to close some loop?

I would also like to change the slide effect to fade in/out (just replacing .slideDown does not do it). Thoughts?

```
function ticker() {
    $('#jsTicker li:first').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).appendTo($('#jsTicker')).slideDown(1500);
    });
}
setInterval(ticker, 6000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/Zh3wU/

Comment: Seems to be working fine on my side.

Comment: I don't see how sliding up or down can crash a browser. Change it to fade and see if it improves.I tried the fiddle and it seems fine. Which browser does it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` is basically an infinite loop.

Your current function does not wait for the slideUp to be done before it starts over again.

Try this with `setTimeout` instead:

```
(function() {
    var tickerTimer;
    function ticker() {
        clearTimeout(tickerTimer);
        $('#jsTicker li:first').slideUp(function() {
            $(this).appendTo($('#jsTicker')).slideDown(1500, function(){
                tickerTimer = setTimeout(ticker, 6000);
            });
        });   
    }
    tickerTimer = setTimeout(ticker, 6000);
})();
```

Comment: @KevinOrin What fading?

Comment: i would also like it to fade instead of slide

Comment: @KevinOrin so fade. use fadeOut.

Comment: @KevinOrin remmeber you are also adding `1500` msec every time (about 1.5 seconds) -- it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Zh3wU/2/

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `setInterval()`. You aren't taking into account the asynchronous behavior of animations.

Try something like the following instead using `setTimeout()`

```
function ticker() {
    $('#jsTicker li:first').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).appendTo($('#jsTicker')).slideDown(1500, function() {
            setTimeout(ticker, 4500);
        });
    });
}
setTimeout(ticker, 6000);
```

Comment: Why `4500`? Random number? And you have a typo -- `ticker`, not `ticket`.

Comment: He wants the animation to occur every 6000 ms. If the Slidedown takes 1500ms, only 4500 more ms is required to hit 6000.

Comment: Corrected the typo, but yea why 2 setTimeOuts? also what about make it fade instead of slide?

Comment: @KevinOrin One or two doesn't make a difference, I could just call a function that triggers the `setTimeout()`. You need to invoke the function initially, can do it immediate or after 6000 ms as your logic  already implies. Also, what is wrong with `fade()`? The element needs to visible and in the DOM before you can fade it.

Comment: so wouldn't i be able to fadeOut first item and fadeIn following

Comment: @KevinOrin You can fadeout/in anything you want, they just need to be visible/invis before you call that function. Also, the timeout should technically be 4100ms since I forgot to account that `slideUp()` takes 400ms by default.